# Let $i: X \to Y$ be the inclusion of a closed subvariety. Then $i$ is a finite morphism

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Statement of the problem:

> Let $i: X \to Y$ be the inclusion of a closed subvariety. Then $i$ is
>   a finite morphism.

Here's my attempt. Please verify it or correct it. Suggestions for improvement are welcome:

I should first show that $i$ is an *affine* morphism, i.e. there exists an open covering $Y = \bigcup_i U_i$ by affine sets $U_i$ such that the open subsets $i^{-1}(U_i)$ are affine.

Since $Y$ is a variety, by definition it can be covered by a finite number of *open affine* sets $U_i$, i.e. $Y=\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$. $X$ is a closed subvariety of $Y$ and $i^{-1}(U_i)=X \cap U_i$ is a closed subvariety of $U_i$ which is affine; therefore, $X \cap U_i$ being a closed subspace of an affine variety must be affine itself. This shows that $i^{-1}(U_i)$ is affine for any $i$ and hence $i$ is an affine morphism.

Now I want to show that each $k[X\cap U_i]$ is finitely generated as a $k[U_i]$-module (i.e. it is of finite type). I do not understand this part well but here's my attempt:

By definition, for an open set $U$ in $X$, a regular function on $U$ is a function of the following form: there is an open cover $U=\cup (X\cap V_{\alpha})$ where the $V_{\alpha}$'s are open subsets of $Y$ such that $f(y)=g_{\alpha}(y)$ on $X \cap V_{\alpha}$ where $g_{\alpha}$ is regular on $V_{\alpha}$.(This is the definition given in Kempf's *Algebraic Varieties*)

Assuming that definition is indeed well-defined, it should be independent of how we cover $U$. But $X \cap U_i$ is an open subset of $X$ and surely it can be covered by itself. Therefore, a regular map on $X \cap U_i$ comes from a regular map on $U_i$. This shows that if $f \in k[X \cap U_i]$, then $f = g_i \times 1$ where $g_i \in k[U_i]$ and therefore, $k[X \cap U_i]$ is generated by the constant function $1$ which is regular on $X \cap U_i$. So, as a $K[U_i]$-module, $K[X \cap U_i]$ is generated by scalar multiples of one element (namely the constant function $1$) and hence is finitely generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all a bit laboured. We can reduce to the affine case: $X=\textrm{Spec}\,R$ and $Y=\textrm{Spec}\,S$. For $i:X\to Y$
to be a closed immersion (the inclusion of a closed variety
is a special case), then the corresponding ring map $S\to R$
is a surjection: basically $R=S/I$ for the ideal $I$ for
which $X=V(I)$. Therefore
$R$ is a finitely-generated $S$-module, and so $i$ is a finite morphism.

Comment: This looks like a wonderful answer but I do not understand two points. (I'm using Kempf's Algebraic Varieties and it defines varieties using spaces of functions. I think your answer is more like the approach Hartshorne uses.) Anyway, can you please fill in these details? 1) Why can we reduce it to the affine case? 2) What is an immersion in algebraic geometry? (never heard of it) Moreover, I agree with you that my solution was too wordy and labored but was it correct?

Comment: @stressedout-gone- Closed immersion is the analogue of closed subvariety for general schemes. As for reduction to the the affine case, it's basically the argument you use: cover $Y$ by affines $U_i$ and then $i^{-1}(U_i)$ by affines $V_{ij}$ and consider the maps $V_{ij}\to U_i$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know about schemes. It's not covered in Kempf's Algebraic Varieties at all. Is it possible to show that the ring map $S \to R$ is surjective in our particular case without knowing about immersions at all?

Comment: @stressedout-gone- I think that's what you're saying at "a regular map ... comes from a regular map ...".

Comment: Right. So, I still have to use the wordy argument I used for that part. Am I right?

Comment: @stressedout: I am not sure if you're still active on this site, but I wanted to ask a question about Kempf's book.  I am using it to start learning algebraic geometry.  How was your experience with this book? For self study?  The fact that his approach is slightly different in the beginning makes me wonder whether I should look into other sources or not.

Comment: @student To be honest, it was a nightmare. However, there might be another reason for my failure to feel comfortable with the book: I had to miss most of the lectures at the university because of seasonal allergy. If you're taking the class with a good professor that explains the parts of the book that are overlooked or are too concise to be fully understood, you will probably do fine. Another problem with the book is that it has too few exercises. I still suggest Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry and Mumford's Redbook of Varieties and Schemes as complementary references.

Comment: @stressedout Thanks! I am doing an independent study with a prof. using it. 
Isn't this book about varieties whereas the two books you mentioned quickly move to schemes? Kempf's book has exercises but they are more of developing the theory than illustrations of it? I was also looking at Andreas Gathmann's notes which look pretty good and have several examples. I have also heard about shafarevich's book. Would you change your suggestion based on the information that I have never seen any algebraic geometry before?

Comment: @stressedout Other things I notes are that a) I have seen Atiyah-Macdonald level commutative algebra but Kempf hardly uses anything. b) Others define affine varieties to explicitly be algebraic sets in affine space, his language is slightly different and uses algebra morphisms into base field (essentially maximal ideals) as the set -- which essentially is the same but took me a while to realize that. I haven't seen that in other sources. That's why I am a bit concerned. 
Do you know about a set of notes written expounding on this text?

Comment: @student I don't recommend it for an independent study without complementary references. Yes, Hartshorne's and Mumford's books discuss schemes too, but they also discuss varieties; Mumford's first section of the three sections in his book discusses varieties if I'm not mistaken. If you are interested in the applications of algebraic varieties, I have heard good things about Using Algebraic Geometry by D. Cox, J. Little and D O'shea. I also highly recommend Atiyah-McDonald's Commutative Algebra. Kempf is like Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. It is too compact and dense.